iPad that's not in use suddenly added to Messages?
Working on a Macbook Pro, a notification appeared that an iPad had been added to Messages, with a link to Settings.  Following that, I confirmed that it is an iPad we own.  Tried to look at the notification again: "No recent notifications."  (Recent means the past five seconds?)
The weird thing is that the iPad has been asleep for at least ninety minutes.  Before that, it was only being used for Mail and to play a game.  The last time Messages was opened on it was more than a week ago.
Why would an idle iPad suddenly get added to Messages?
